# ElasticSearch build query depending a condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch

I want to know if it's possible to build a query depending some conditions in my code.

```
self.search(query: {
                    bool: {
                      must: [
                        { term: { country_id: country_id }},
                        { term: { region_id: region_id }} => if region_id is not nil
]
                    }
                  }
```

In this example, I would like to add the line:

```
{ term: { region_id: region_id }}
```

ONLY if region_id is not nil/ present in my method.

In SQL I can build a query with multilines and conditions.
Can I do the same with ES ?

Info: working in ruby here

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you can do it like the programming way, but need to do this in the query itself.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood your question :-). This was only in your code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to create a query variable to build the query, and conditionally add the elements (terms) that you want.  Give this a try:

```
# Start with a base search definition
query = { 
  query: {
    bool: {
      must: [
        { term: { country_id: country_id }}
      ]
    }
  }
}

# Conditionally add search terms
if region_id is not nil
  query[:query][:bool][:must] << { term: { region_id: region_id }}
end

# Execute the search
self.search(query)
```

Comment: Perfect answer ! Didn't know that I can use the syntax: `query[:query][:bool][:must]`Thanks !